# Typescript - interface where property takes itself as a parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a type where one of the properties is a class that takes that type as a parameter

```
interface Type<P extends {}> {
  name: string;
  props: P;
  field: new(type: Type<P>) => { ... };
}

// Define some Types
interface AllTypes {
  Foo: Type<{}>;
  Bar: Type<{
    foo: string;
    bar: number
  }>
}
type SomeType = AllTypes[keyof AllTypes];
```

I have a function that takes a `SomeType` and tries to instantiate its `field`, but I get an error

```
function f(type: SomeType) {
  return new type.field(type);  // Error
}
```

Changing `Type.field` to `new(type: SomeType) => ...` will solve this error, but will create further errors down the line:

```
class Field<T extends SomeType> {
  type: T;
  constructor(type: T) {
    this.type = type;
  }
}
declare class FooField extends Field<AllTypes['Foo']> {}
declare class BarField extends Field<AllTypes['Bar']> {}

const fields: SomeType[] = [
  {
    name: 'foo',
    props: {},
    field: FooField,
  },
  {
    name: 'bar',
    props: {  // This error is expected and desired
      foo: 0,
      bar: 'hi',
    },
    field: BarField,  // Error
  },
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you look for:

```
interface Type<P extends {}> {
  name: string;
  props: P;
  field: new<T extends Type<any>>(type: T) => { };
}
```